# How can I generate static files from a pugjs project correctly?

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

I work with a site that was builded using Pugjs as a template engine and I've been experiencing an error when I try to generate the static files using the command 'npm generate'. The projecto also has other commands but only fails when I try to generate the static files. The error that I have is this one:

`    Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/da6b1f3a-77e2-4b7c-993a-9d56b65f637e

```
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[app ready] http://localhost:3000
[13:33:28] Finished 'app' after 887 ms
[13:33:28] Starting 'pages'...
[13:33:28] 'pages' errored after 7.74 ms
[13:33:28] Error: spawn wget ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[13:33:28] 'generate' errored after 4.45 min
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! weiser@1.0.0 generate: `gulp generate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weiser@1.0.0 generate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JORGE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-24T19_33_28_314Z-debug.log`
```

Hope you help me to find a solution to fix the issue with the command.

PSD: I'm using node 13.12.0

I've tried to generate the static files of the pugjs project but it returns an error

Comment: What steps have you followed to get to this point?

Comment: I've been following the project command to generate that is npm run generate but it throws that error. Is there any command that I can use to translate all the files from that pugjs project to static files?

Comment: It depends on how the project is configured. There's a mention of Gulp in the error log. Is there a gulpfile?